# What is bundleID for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, appium, bundle-identifier

I want to run Xcode via Appium and I need Xcode bundeId (like com.apple.TextEdit). I use Appium2 and driver 'Mac2'.

Capabilities:

"platformName": "Mac",
"appium:automationName": "Mac2",
"appium:bundleId": "com.apple.Xcode"

When I try to start my test, I receive error:

`Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The app representing com.apple.Xcode could not be found.`

What is bundleId for Xcode?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle identifier for Xcode is `com.apple.dt.Xcode`

You can find it like so (run in terminal)

```
defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info CFBundleIdentifier
```